# Automatically use secret when pulling from private registry

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to globally (or at least per namespace), configure kubernetes to always use an image pull secret when connecting to a private repo? 
There are two use cases:

1. when a user specifies a container in our private registry in a deployment
2. when a user points a Helm chart at our private repo (and so we have no control over the image pull secret tag).

I know it is possible to do this on a [service account basis](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry) but without writing a controller to add this to every new service account created it would get a bit of a mess.

Is there are way to set this globally so if kube tries to pull from registry X it uses secret Y?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know, usually the **default** serviceAccount is responsible for pulling the images.
To easily add imagePullSecrets to a serviceAccount you can use the **patch command**:

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "mySecret"}]}'
```

It's possible to use `kubectl patch` in a script that inserts imagePullSecrets on serviceAccounts across all namespaces.

If it´s too complicated to manage multiple namespaces you can have look at [kubernetes-replicator](https://github.com/mittwald/kubernetes-replicator), which syncs resources between namespaces.

**Solution 2:**
[This section of the doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#configuring-nodes-to-authenticate-to-a-private-registry) explains how you can set the private registry on a node basis:

> Here are the recommended steps to configuring your nodes to use a
>   private registry. In this example, run these on your desktop/laptop:
>
> 1. Run `docker login [server]` for each set of credentials you want to use. This updates `$HOME/.docker/config.json`.
> 2. View `$HOME/.docker/config.json` in an editor to ensure it contains just the credentials you want to use.
> 3. Get a list of your nodes, for example:
>
>    - If you want the names:
>        nodes=$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range.items[*].metadata}{.name} {end}')
>    - If you want to get the IPs:
>        nodes=$(kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")]}{.address} {end}')
> 4. Copy your local .docker/config.json to one of the search paths list above. for example:
>
>    for n in $nodes; do scp ~/.docker/config.json root@$n:/var/lib/kubelet/config.json; done

**Solution 3:**
A (very dirty!) way I discovered to not need to set up an imagePullSecret on a deployment / serviceAccount basis is to:

1. Set ImagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
2. Pulling the image in each node
   2.1. manually using `docker pull myrepo/image:tag`.
   2.2. using a script or a tool like [docker-puller](https://github.com/glowdigitalmedia/docker-puller) to automate that process.

Well, I think I don't need to explain how ugly is that.

**PS**: If it helps, I found [an issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/2505) on kubernetes/kops about the feature of creating a global configuration for private registry.

Comment: I went for solution2.  User adds b64 encoded docker config to AWS secrets, passes the ARN to terraform which creates AWS launch config userdata to pull the secret out and put in on any worker the asg spins up :)

Answer (score -1):

Two simple questions, where are you running your k8s cluster? Where is your registry located? 
Here there are a few approaches to your issue: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry

Comment: Running on EKS and the registry is a private artifactory