# How to pass imagePullSecrets from commandline

Tags: kubernetes

I am using kubernetes imperative way instead of declarative.
As there are many parameters changing regularly and can't update the yaml file every time.

For creating a deployment, we use this

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx:1.7.1
```

This is fine for public images.
But for provate images, we need to pass credentials data using secrets.As in [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)
If it is yaml file, we keep in the file below line.

```
 imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

But, how to pass this data for below type of line.?

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx:1.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here example for adding image-pull-secrets in command line

```
kubectl run hello-world -it --restart=Never --image=nginx:1.7.1 --image-pull-secrets=regcred
```

For overriding, you can use :

```
kubectl run <name> -it --restart=Never --image=<private image> --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "v1", "spec": {"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "<secret>"}]} }'
```

Comment: run is for creating a pod but for deployment, this parameter is not supporting

Comment: @udaykiran you want to run parameter that's why added if you want to creat deployment you can add it using file it will be also helpful to manage better way.

Comment: Sorry Harsh, I never mentioned that I need run parameter.i am sorry if I create any confusion. And I need imperative one and I mentioned reason for that also. Please let me know if any option or parameter available for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can still manage Kubernetes with `kubectl` the same way using configuration files. There's no need to resort to complicated command line arguments. Just create your deployment manifest like normal. For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Then imperatively commit the manifest to the Kubernetes API Server:

`kubectl create -f deployment.yml`

Comment: run is for creating a pod but for deployment, this parameter is not supporting.
Declarative way is good. But we need imperative for this, as we are integrating with jenkins and users require multiple copies of this deployment running. So, for each job build, there should be a separate copy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to [Add ImagePullSecrets to a service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account).

This might help you:

> If the pod does not have a ServiceAccount set, it sets the
>   ServiceAccount to default. It ensures that the ServiceAccount
>   referenced by the pod exists, and otherwise rejects it. If the pod
>   does not contain any ImagePullSecrets, then ImagePullSecrets of the
>   ServiceAccount are added to the pod.

patch serviceaccount you use and set imagePullSecrets equal to your chosen secret.

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount <account> -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "regcred"}]}'
```

You may also find interesting [Automatically use secret when pulling from private registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223075/automatically-use-secret-when-pulling-from-private-registry/55230340#55230340) thread.