# How to pull a docker image from AWS ECR to Minikube Kubernetes cluster with MFA enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, minikube, amazon-ecr

I have a docker image in AWS ECR which is in my secondary account. I want to pull that image to the Minikube Kubernetes cluster using AWS IAM Role ARN where MFA is enabled on it. Due to this, my deployment failed while pulling the Image.

I enabled the registry-creds addon to access ECR Image but didn't work out.

May I know any other way to access AWS ECR of AWS Account B via AWS IAM Role ARN with MFA enabled using the credential of the AWS Account A?

For example, I provided details like this

- Enter AWS Access Key ID: **Access key of Account A**
- Enter AWS Secret Access Key: **Secret key of Account A**
- (Optional) Enter AWS Session Token:
- Enter AWS Region: **us-west-2**
- Enter 12 digit AWS Account ID (Comma separated list): [**AccountA, AccountB**]
- (Optional) Enter ARN of AWS role to assume: <**role_arn of AccountB**>

**ERROR MESSAGE:**
`Warning  Failed     2s (x3 over 42s)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "XXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/sample-dev:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head "https://XXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/v2/sample-dev/manifests/latest": no basic auth credentials`

`Warning  Failed     2s (x3 over 42s)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull`

Answer (score 3):

Minikube doesn't have a way to provide the MFA token.  You need to create temporary credentials somehow and provide those credentials to [`minikube addons configure registry-creds`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/).

My day job uses [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault) and so my typical sequence for setting this up involves running

```sh
aws-vault exec some-profile -- env | grep AWS
minikube addons configure registry-creds
```

and then copying the temporary access key (starts with `ASIA...`), secret, *and session token* into the Minikube configuration.  I do not enter a role ARN in the final prompt; the temporary credentials are already associated with the right AWS role.

The same restrictions and workaround would apply if you were [using the Kubernetes-level `imagePullSecrets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

Comment: Thanks @David for your answer. Let me try it out

Answer (score 3):

While the `minikube addons` based solution shown by @DavidMaze is probably cleaner and generally preferable, I wasn't able to get it to work.

Instead, I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223075/automatically-use-secret-when-pulling-from-private-registry) it is possible to give the service account of the pod a copy of the docker login tokens in the local home. If you haven't set a serviceaccount, it's `default`:

```sh
# Log in with aws ecr get-login or however
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
  --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=$HOME/.docker/config.json \
  --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "regcred"}]}'
```

This will work fine in a bind.