# Access private registry on kubernetes cluster from any namespace

Tags: kubernetes, devops

Can someone please help me troubleshoot an issue I'm having with my deployed apps on my Kubernetes cluster? I am attempting to split them into different namespaces, but I am encountering an error when trying to deploy an app with the same settings, except for the namespace. Currently, I am working with a K3s on-prem cluster and pulling my images from a private registry (Gitlab Registry) using a secret to access it. The apps are currently working fine in the default namespace, but when I try to deploy an app to a custom namespace, I get the following error message:

`Failed to pull image "<image-path>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "<image-path>": failed to resolve reference "<image-path>": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden`

I'm looking for a more efficient solution to grant access to a private Docker registry in Kubernetes without having to manually create a Secret and a ServiceAccount in every namespace I create.

I have already tried the following approach, which works but is time-consuming:

1. Create the `Secret` in the namespace where the Docker credentials are stored:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret-name> \
    --docker-server=<registry-url> \
    --docker-username=<username> \
    --docker-password=<access-token> \
    --docker-email=<email> \
    --namespace=<namespace>
```

2. Create a `ServiceAccount` to access the private registry:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount <service-account-name> -n <namespace>
```

3. Create and apply a role and a role binding that grants the necessary permissions to access the private registry:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
name: <role-name>
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get"]
- apiGroups: ["extensions"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
name: <role-binding-name>
roleRef:
apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
kind: Role
name: <role-name>
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
name: <service-account-name>
namespace: <namespace>
```

4. Add the `Secret` to the `ServiceAccount` in the respective namespace:

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount <service-account-name> -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "<secret-name>"}]}' -n <namespace>
```

Is there a way to set up the permissions to access a private registry globally, so that any new namespace I create automatically has access to the registry without me having to manually create the Secret and ServiceAccount in each one?

I appreciate any advice or guidance on how to achieve this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically use secret when pulling from private registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223075/automatically-use-secret-when-pulling-from-private-registry)

Answer (score 3):

You could either use a Kyverno ClusterPolicy or imagepullsecret-patcher

This is documented very well in the posts below:

https://devopstales.github.io/kubernetes/k8s-imagepullsecret-patcher/
https://kubesandclouds.com/index.php/2021/12/13/cluster-wide-registry-auth/